# Restrict input to positive numbers in react-select's Creatable

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to use react-select's Creatable for an input field of type number. Code below.

```
import React from 'react';
import Tooltip from '@atlaskit/tooltip';
import Creatable from "react-select/creatable";
import  { components } from 'react-select';


const Input = props => {
  if (props.isHidden) {
    return <components.Input {...props} />;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Tooltip content={'Custom Input'}>
        <components.Input {...props} type="number"/>
      </Tooltip>
    </div>
  );
};

const handleInputChange = (value,action) => {
  console.log(value);
  console.log(action);
}

export default () => (
  <Creatable
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    components={{ Input }}
    backspaceRemovesValue
    isClearable
    onInputChange={handleInputChange}
  />
);
```

When I type a - or e the onInputChange is not trigerred and the value of the Creatable is not being set. Also if I try to remove the symbols using a backspace it does not work either. Any idea on how to restrict the input to positive numbers only?

[Here is a codesandbox example to see what is happening.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-veqo1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The react-select library provides us with a `onKeyDown` prop that will pass on the event to the callback function.So, all I had to do was use this prop and then prevent default if the user enters a character that I am not expecting them to enter.

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-3k8uk)